# How can I reovle pip install git on conda environment in Mac Pro M1?

Tags: git, macos, github, pip, conda

I am trying to install git repo on conda environment and getting unable to connect to github.com. I was able to clone git repo using $git clone <repo_name>
in the same machine without any error. It would be a great help if you have any suggestions.

```bash
py3.8) user2@node1 /tmp % pip install git+git://github.com/kLabUM/rrcf.git     
Collecting git+git://github.com/kLabUM/rrcf.git
  Cloning git://github.com/kLabUM/rrcf.git to /private/var/folders/25/vqnx0dh53y7clwgprnzshhxr0000gn/T/pip-req-build-2euzqvpc
  Running command git clone --filter=blob:none --quiet git://github.com/kLabUM/rrcf.git /private/var/folders/25/vqnx0dh53y7clwgprnzshhxr0000gn/T/pip-req-build-2euzqvpc
  fatal: unable to connect to github.com:
  github.com[0: 20.207.73.82]: errno=Operation timed out

  error: subprocess-exited-with-error
  
  × git clone --filter=blob:none --quiet git://github.com/kLabUM/rrcf.git /private/var/folders/25/vqnx0dh53y7clwgprnzshhxr0000gn/T/pip-req-build-2euzqvpc did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 128
  ╰─> See above for output.
  
  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: subprocess-exited-with-error

× git clone --filter=blob:none --quiet git://github.com/kLabUM/rrcf.git /private/var/folders/25/vqnx0dh53y7clwgprnzshhxr0000gn/T/pip-req-build-2euzqvpc did not run successfully.
│ exit code: 128
╰─> See above for output.

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
(py3.8) user2@node1 /tmp %
```

Comment: The issue seems quite clear: _"unable to connect to github.com"_. So either Github is down, or there's an issue with your connection.

Comment: `git://` protocol is no longer supported at Github. Use `https://` or `ssh://` Like this: `pip install git+https://github.com/kLabUM/rrcf.git`